# ELK Stack (Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana) with concurrent remote syslog server?

Tags: freebsd, syslog, logstash, kibana, elk

I'm building a log analyser service to start monitoring mainly our pfSense Firewalls, XenServer Hypervisors, FreeBSD/Linux servers and Windows servers.

There's a lot of documentation on the internet about the ELK stack and how to make it work nicely. But I would like to use it in a different manner, but I don't know if it's a good solution or just a waste of time/disk space.

I already have a FreeBSD 10.2 machine acting as a remote syslog server, and my ideia is to simply concentrate all the logs on this machine and them the syslog server forwards the logs with `logstash-forwarder` to the ELK server.

It's clear to me that this approach will raise the disk requirements for this setup, but in other hand I will have only one machine with the `logstash-forwarder` daemon installed, which seems good to me.

But talking about problems. The `logstash` parser matches `[host]` with the hostname of the server sending the log messages, and in this approach there's only on "server" show on ELK, the remote syslog server.

I'm aware that I can customize the settings on the `logstash` configuration files but I don't know (and I don't have the experience to know) if this is just a simple setting on the parsers of it if will compromise the entire ELK experience.

In the end I just want some advices about my logging architecture and if it will work, or if I should go without other option.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm sure what you want to do is possible, but details about what format you're logging in on the central syslog server, the logging rate, etc would be great. Also, asking a specific question will get you much better responses than simply saying "I'm lost, please help".

Comment: Have you considered graylog? You can use the graylog syslog input to ingest syslog into elasticsearch. From there you can use Kibana and graylog has a syslog/pfsense extractor available.

Comment: Logstash also has a [syslog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-syslog.html) input...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to change the `host` field in logstash output with `ruby` filter without much hassle.

```
    ruby {
            code => "
                    event['host'] = event['message'].split(' ')[3]
                   "
    }
```

Here I assumed in the syslog server logs, the host field is the fourth field where white space is the separator.